# Are the rules generated by decision tree learner algorithm correlated?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have been working on decision tree learner algorithm to detect fraudulent bank transactions.
So far,I have generated rule set for decision tree based on my data-set.
I have also generated significance value for each rule: how many transactions from my data-set satisfy a particular rule, what percentage of fraud the rule captures, etc.
Now, depending upon the significance of the rules, I need to select top Ten rules.

My Question is when I select the top ten rules, is there any chance that some of the rules are correlated?

For example:
The data-set I am working on has 10000 transactions.
The decision tree algorithm gives me 20 rules.
Out of the 20 rules, I need to select the top ten rules.
Now, suppose rule1 identifies 50 transactions, and rule2 identifies 60 transactions.  What is the chance that some of the rules identified by rule1 are also identified by rule2?

Note:The top ten transaction are the ones catching most of the frauds.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot derive a probability this way.  The correlation is a characteristic property of the data set, something you compute for each situation.  It is *not* something you can algebraically derive from the given information.  The answer to your example could vary over the entire theoretical range: 0 through 50.

In this application, you would have to individually tally which transactions satisfy which rules (10000 * 20 list) and compute the correlations from those real statistics.

One field of determining the interactions and individual validity is "cross validation".  For instance, you would remove one rule from the collection, re-run the model on the transactions, and see what changes come to your validation metrics (accuracy, recall, etc.).  This is often the first step in Principal Component Analysis.

I do note that you haven't defined "top ten rules".  Are these the ten rules which, taken individually, catch the most transactions?  The ones whose individual absence misses the most transactions?  Perhaps you need the set of ten rules that, collectively, have the highest accuracy?  These are three distinctly different problems, and depend on the correlation you ask about.